# matplotlib: ylabels of subplots overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three subplots sharing x-axis. I need hspace between subplots to be 0.0, but then  y-labels of subplots overlap.

[ylabels of subplots overlap](http://translatina.pl/ylabelsProblem.png)

Is there any way to move extreme y-labels of each subplot a little bit downwards or upwards (as I did manually in mspaint, on the right)?

Piotr

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated ticker formater class exactly for this purpose.
http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))  #remove highest label so it wont overlapp with stacked plot.
```

Edit: 
Actually this wont move them, just remove the overlapping ticks.