# pandas pie charts subplots labels overlap with slice labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972033/matplotlib-ylabels-of-subplots-overlapping), I am using the `subplots` keyword in `matplotlib` except I am drawing pie charts and using pandas.

The labels on my `subplots` crash with the slice labels when the labels are close to horizontal:

```
first = pd.Series({'True':2316, 'False': 64})
second = pd.Series({'True':2351, 'False': 29})
df = pd.concat([first, second], axis=1, keys=['First pie', 'Second pie'])
axes = df.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True)
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image: First pie example]

I can alleviate this somewhat by doing as [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#pie-plot) do and adding an explicit `figsize`, but it still looks pretty cramped:

```
axes = df.plot(kind='pie', figsize=[10, 4], subplots=True)
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image: Second pie example]

Is there a nice way to do better. Something to do with `tight_layout` maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the label to the left using [`ax.yaxis.set_label_coords()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.YAxis.set_label_coords.html?highlight=matplotlib%20axis%20yaxis%20set_label_coords#matplotlib.axis.YAxis.set_label_coords), and then adjust the coords to a value that suits you.

The two inputs to `set_label_coords` are the `x` and `y` coordinate of the label, in Axes fraction coordinates.

For your plot, I found (-0.15, 0.5) to work well (i.e. `x=-0.15` means 15% of the axes width to the left of the axes, and `y=0.5` means half way up the axes). In general then, assuming you always want the label to be centered on the y axis, you only need to adjust the `x` coordinate.

I also added some space between the plots using [`subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust) so that the axes label didn't then overlap with the `False` label from the other pie.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

first = pd.Series({'True':2316, 'False': 64})
second = pd.Series({'True':2351, 'False': 29})
df = pd.concat([first, second], axis=1, keys=['First pie', 'Second pie'])
axes = df.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True)
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.15, 0.5)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This answer leaves the pies looking great! But I went for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46528245/2071807) as the chosen one, even though the resulting pies are not quite as nice, but because there's less case-specific experimentation required with `labelpad` than `set_label_coords`.

Comment: Well ok, whatever works for you. Glad you're happy with your plots now. I'm not sure I understand your point about experimentation though... I mean, you're really just changing one number for both cases, no?

Comment: Don't you have to do experimentation with two parameters in `set_label_coords` and only one with `labelpad`?

Comment: Well, you can leave the y coordinate at 0.5, assuming you want it half way up the plot. It's only the x coordinate you care about, but I guess this does give you added flexibility if you do happen to want to move the label up or down.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that was what was going on. Might be worth updating the answer to show that the `0.5` is not part of the customisation.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need padding of lables in y-axis so use labelpad i.e `ax.yaxis.labelpad = 20`

```
axes = df.plot(kind='pie', figsize=[10, 4], subplots=True)
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.yaxis.labelpad = 20
```

[image]